# Spring Boot Trasnsaction Stop Auto Commit or Rollback when some other Transaction Fails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

Everone,

I am learning springboot with Mysql and trying to concentrate on Transactions. I am following the below link for guidance :

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-managing-transactions/tree/master/complete

When i execute the first transaction `Alice, Bob and Carol` gets saved.

When i execute the Second transaction `Chris or Samuel` gets discarded because Samuel has violated DB constraints.

All i want to know now is, 
1. Is there a way to rollback the first Transaction when second Transaction Fails ? 
2. Save all transaction when everything is completed...

Comment: "Is there a way to rollback the first Transaction when second Transaction Fails" -> That's not how transactions work. Wrap everything in one transaction if you want to rollback on error.

Comment: @msparer Thanks. Is there a way to stop committing values to database on another transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You just have to declare both transactions into 2 different methods and annotate them with **`@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)`** from the first transaction method.

For more details study transaction propagation : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html.